# What are the best practices on communicating with container views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been using container VCs often recently and I have been wondering what is the best way to communicate between the main Vc and the container VCs. Right now im using notifications, but I would rather use something better. How can I obtain a pointer to the container VCs so that I can at least use delegation?  Any better ways?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard with a container view and an embed segue, or are you creating and connecting the view controllers in code?

Comment: Vc with a container inside. Using storyboards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is up to the container view controller to set up any necessary connections between itself and the embedded view controller, in its `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

In iOS programming, we have a pattern for this style of communication betwixt view controllers.  You can read about it in [“Coordinating Efforts Between View Controllers” in the *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW1).

But I think it's easier to understand with a concrete example.  Let's use the Google Maps app for iPhone:

[image: Google Maps app for iPhone]

I don't know exactly how this app is implemented.  But let's suppose there's a top-level `AppViewController` that manages the search bar (at the top) and the location bar (at the bottom), and it embeds a `MapViewController` in a container view.

There are some interactions between the view controllers.  When the user searches, the `AppViewController` needs to tell the `MapViewController` to place some map markers and zoom in on one of them.  When the user taps a map marker, the `MapViewController` needs to tell the `AppViewController` to display information about that marker in the location bar at the bottom.

So here's the pattern.

First, we define a protocol for the messages that the `MapViewController` (which is the embedded view controller) will send to the `AppViewController` (which is the container view controller):

```
@class MapMarker;
@class MapViewController;

@protocol MapViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)mapViewController:(MapViewController *)mapViewController didSelectMarker:(MapMarker *)marker;

@end
```

We will make the `AppViewController` conform to this protocol.  So the `MapViewController` doesn't need to know about the `AppViewController` specifically.  It just needs a reference to some object that conforms to the protocol.  The `MapViewController` also needs to understand a message that sets its markers and a message that zooms to a specific marker.  So we declare `MapViewController` like this:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MapViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (void)setMarkers:(NSArray *)markers;
- (void)zoomToMarker:(MapMarker *)marker;

@end
```

Note that the `delegate` property is `weak` to avoid a retain cycle.

The `AppViewController` needs to conform to the `MapViewControllerDelegate` protocol.  Usually we declare that conformance in a class extension in `AppViewController.m`, since conformance doesn't need to be part of `AppViewController`'s public interface.  The `AppViewController` also needs a reference to the `MapViewController`.

```
@interface AppViewController () <MapViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) MapViewController *mapViewController;

@end
```

Next, we go into the storyboard, select the embed segue, and give it an identifier:

[image: embed segue identifier]

Now we can implement the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method to wire up the properties:

```
@implementation AppViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MapEmbedding"]) {
        [self prepareForMapEmbeddingSegue:segue sender:sender];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForMapEmbeddingSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    self.mapViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    self.mapViewController.delegate = self;

    // We can do any additional setup on mapViewController here,
    // like set its initial viewport.
}
```

Note that `AppViewController` also has to implement `mapviewController:didSelectMarker:`, and `MapViewController` needs to implement `setMarkers:` and `zoomToMarker:`.