# interactions between presented and embedded view controllers

Tags: ios

- VC1 embeds VC2 in a container view. VC2 is a table VC.
- Clicking a cell in VC2 pushes VC3.
- VC3 embeds VC4 in a container view.

[image: visual]
How do I get a **reference to VC1 from within VC4.m**?

I tried `self.parentViewController.presentingViewController.parentViewController` and `self.parentViewController.presentingViewController` but they didn't seem to work.

But then I decided to see if it would work when I used the delegate to store a reference to VC1, and still I was getting null for all of the public properties on VC1. Would VC1 not be in memory in this scenario? If not, why not? If so, why else would its (strong) properties be null?

edit: I've also just discovered through NSLogs that `viewDidLoad` in VC4 executes before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in VC2 finishes executing and setting the delegate reference, which may explain why that approach isn't working. How do I ensure the next VC is pushed only at the completion of all other lines in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`? And regardless, there are other public properties on VC1 that are already set (not null) prior to a row being selected (I've just verified this with an NSLog in `didSelectRow` in VC2), and they are turning up null when I attempt to access them through VC4 through any approach.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */

// set reference to selected convo. it is stored in ConversationsParentVC public property
self.conversationsParentVC.selectedConvo = self.conversationsParentVC.conversationsArray[indexPath.row];

// temp
AppDelegate *delegate = getAppDelegate;
delegate.activeVC = self.conversationsParentVC;
ConversationsParentVC *convosParentVC = (ConversationsParentVC*)delegate.activeVC;
NSLog(@"boop %@", delegate.activeVC);
NSLog(@"beep %i", convosParentVC.conversationsArray.count);
}
```

[image: stack trace]

Comment: Post your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` source code.

Comment: @robmayoff Not much to it, but I've posted it. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?  What is the stack trace when VC4's `viewDidLoad` is called?

Comment: @robmayoff Yes, I am using a storyboard. I've never looked at a stack trace before, but hopefully that is helpful.

Comment: Why do you need the reference? Chances are you should pass some object (proxied or by protocol) during the segue rather than try to navigate the VC hierarchy.

Comment: @Wain I'm open to using prepareForSegue or whatever is best, but it's not obvious to me that that would be simpler. And anyway, I want to understand the VC hierarchy better.

Comment: @Wain Also, I'm interested to know what it means to pass a proxied object. Not knowing any better, if I passed an object during a segue, I would just set a public property on the destination VC.

Comment: your navigation controller is in vc1 or vc2? Are you using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set up a push segue from a table view cell, the segue fires before the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method is called.  You need to pass your information on to the destination view controller in the source view controller's `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

Also, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17397775/77567) helpful.

You may also find it useful to know that the `sender` argument in `prepareForSegue:sender:` is the table view cell, and the table view's `indexPathForSelectedRow` has already been set to the cell's index path.